# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, jsonp

```
 jsonp = (url, callback) => {
        var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
        window[callbackName] = function(data) {
            delete window[callbackName];
            document.body.removeChild(script);
            callback(data);
        };

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

componentDidMount() {
 this.jsonp('https://www.naver.com', function(data) {
            alert(data.meta.description);
        });
}
```

But I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error...

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which line do you get the error on? I don't see any `<` in your snippet above.

Comment: The error is on  'componentDidMount()' you have to write 'function componentDidMount()'

Comment: You have not forgot to transpile your code from JSX into JS?

Comment: i replace the code
omponentDidMount() {
 this.jsonp('https://www.naver.com');
}
but same error occur...

Comment: did you enable `ES Class Fields & Static Properties` (currently stage 3) on your babel config?

Comment: What does `https://www.naver.com` return?  It should be json not html

Comment: i want xml data. but when i use XMLHttpRequest, the cors occurs.
so i use jsonp.. how can i get the xml data using jsonp...

Answer (score -1):

In your `.babelrc` file

```
 {
    "presets":[
        "react-app"
    ]
}
```

And then
`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react-app`

This is what create react app uses and is mostly updated to handle the latest syntax.

Comment: That will not change the HTML document at `https://www.naver.com` into JSONP. It will still be HTML.